# Generate Database Report in Python

Tags: python-3.x, database, reporting

I have been trying to generate a report PDF format from Postgres database table without a success. For your information, I am completely new to Python.

The table name is 'signup'. It has 4 fields: Name, Username, Password, Mobile.

I need to generate a report with the following design:

```
Name     Username     Password    Mobile
----------------------------------------
( list of user records will print here )
```

What is the best practice to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

Did you had a look to the reportlab library? I was not happy about that in spite of the fact that in one way or the other it worked reasonably well.

By Fabio.